# Heroku - mvnw is ignored when using Deploy to Heroku button

Tags: java, heroku

I want Heroku to run my `mvnw` script when using a Deploy to Heroku button.  Currently Heroku ignores the script, downloads `mvn`, and runs it.  My `mvnw` file is at the project root and *does* have the 755 (chmod+x) correctly attributed via git.  Everything is as expected when I log through the console (`mvnw` is indeed 755 executable on the dyno, and does run from the console using `./mvnw`).

The reason I want to run my own `mvnw` is that my application is a self-contained fat jar, already available on `bintray`.  All I need is to download the file with curl and run it with the `Procfile`.  Downloading and running mvn is just a waste of time - it works, but is overkill.

So two related questions really

1. Why is an executable `mvnw` not picked up when using the Deploy to `Heroku` button.
2. Is there another way to tell `Heroku` not to run `mvn` but to run some other script to perform compile/install.

Answer (score 0):

Editing my answer because I'm a new contributor and cannot yet comment (!) - an upvote would be nice so I gain reputation.

- I specifically need a "Self-Service", "No Install" deploy. This rules out installing the Heroku plugin, and using the Heroku Maven plugin.
- Using buildpacks works fine with the Deploy to Heroku button. The application deploys in a matter of seconds using the following recipe (edited as per Malak's suggestion to use the official JDK buildpack)

  I edited my `app.json` file to use two buildpacks from the Heroku community catalog.

```
{
  "name": "AppName",
  "description": "Description of App",
  "repository": "https://github.com/myrepo", 
  "image": "heroku/java",
  "buildpacks": [ 
    {
      "url": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://github.com/weibeld/heroku-buildpack-run"
    }
  ]
}
```

- The first build pack installs Java but does not run Maven.
- The second buildpack by default runs a script called `buildpack-run.sh` .

`buildpack-run.sh` just fetches a pre-compiled fat jar.

```
#!/bin/sh -x
curl -L "https://dl.bintray.com/.../publicresults-4.4.2.jar" -o publicresults.jar
```

It is necessary to run `git update-index --chmod=+x buildpack-run.sh` so the script is executable when checked out.

In order to run the Main class inside the fat jar, the following Procfile is used. The application opens the port that Heroku gives it via $PORT.

```
web: java -Dport=$PORT -Xmx512m -Xms128m -cp publicresults.jar app.owlcms.publicresults.Main
```

Comment: See my answer for another option. If you want to go your route, I suggest you use Heroku's official https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common buildpack which is actively maintained and also installs just the JVM without building your source.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku's Java buildpack does not only check for `mvnw`, but also `.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties` to determine if Maven wrapper should be used. It it also not run when you specify a Maven version in `system.properties`. You might be able to get it working by adding an empty `.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties`, but I don't recommend going this route.

It looks like you don't want to actually use Maven wrapper but a custom build script to build your application. You have two options here:

1. You could use [Heroku's Maven plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin) to deploy your fat-jar. This will upload your JAR and a generated Procfile for you and it will work without installing Maven during the build process.
2. You could write a custom buildpack if you want full control over the build process. Buildpacks are, in essence, a bunch of scripts that are run to create a runnable app image from your source. This requires some effort from your side, and I think the Maven plugin route might be a better fit for your use-case, but I didn't want to leave this unmentioned. You can read more about buildpacks here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api